# Views/Operations on Array with flexible number of dimensions

Tags: julia

Is there an elegant and short way to write the functions that are written below in one go, in a single definition? So that the function operates on an array with flexible number of dimensions, adding the `:`s as needed? Ideally, so that it also with `N` dimensions.

```
ind = 1:5

view_something(A::AbstractArray{T,1}, ind) where {T} = view(A, ind)
view_something(A::AbstractArray{T,2}, ind) where {T} = view(A, :, ind)
view_something(A::AbstractArray{T,3}, ind) where {T} = view(A, :, :, ind)

view_something(rand(10,10,10), ind)
view_something(rand(10,10), ind)
view_something(rand(10), ind)
```

I noticed that one can call the `Colon` operator and assemble func args in a vector like that `[Colon(),Colon(),...]`, is this the way to go or are there other ways that are preferred?

Comment: There is a package provding an operator (`..`, IIRC) for exactly that, which works like `...` in Numpy arrays. But I forgot how it is called... :(

Comment: @phipsgabler EllipsisNotation.jl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eachslice(A, dims = d)` gives you an iterator where all other dimensions are `:`

`selectdim(A, d, ind)` gives you the individual index.

From the help prompt: `?selectdim`:

```
  selectdim(A, d::Integer, i)

  Return a view of all the data of A where the index for dimension d equals i.

  Equivalent to view(A,:,:,...,i,:,:,...) where i is in position d.

  See also: eachslice.
```

and `?eachslice`:

```
  eachslice(A::AbstractArray; dims)

  Create a generator that iterates over dimensions dims of A, returning views that select all the data from the other
  dimensions in A.

  Only a single dimension in dims is currently supported. Equivalent to (view(A,:,:,...,i,:,: ...)) for i in axes(A,
  dims)), where i is in position dims.
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted and couldn't find. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Haven't you missed the parameter `d` in `selectdim(A,ind)`?

Comment: Hah, yep. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
ind = 1:5
view_something(A::AbstractArray{T,N}, ind) where {T, N} = 
      view(A, [Colon() for i in 1:(N-1)]..., ind)

view_something(rand(10,10,10), ind)
view_something(rand(10,10), ind)
view_something(rand(10), ind)
```

Answer (score 1):

[EllipsisNotation.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/EllipsisNotation.jl) has been written for exactly this purpose and lets you do that conveniently, similar to how the `...` operator in Numpy works:

```
view_something(A::AbstractArray{T}, ind) where {T} = view(A, .., ind)
```